# Cleanup function fails the first time using AbortController

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-hooks, code-cleanup

Im using `AbortController` to cancel the `fetch` promise on unmount React lifecycle.
For some reason, the cleanup is **not working the FIRST TIME the element unmounts**.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`, { signal })
      .then(sleeper(1)) // Create some latency
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        setData(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setData(error);
      });
    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    };
  }, [name]);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-stallman-hmh00?file=/src/App.js:308-742)

Follow the next steps:

1. Access de demo link.
2. Click `Show/hide pokemon` button TWICE quicly to **force the abort** of the child `Pokemon` react element.
3. Check the error in console: `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component`
4. Repeat step 2. Click `Show/hide pokemon` button TWICE quicly to **force the abort** of the child `Pokemon` react element.
5. **No errors found** this time and subsequent retries. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)

> **Note:** When `abort()` is called, the `fetch()` promise rejects with a
>   `DOMException` named `AbortError`.

When component unmounts and `abort` invoked, the `fetch` rejects with error. The error is caught and this code is attempting to set state with the error. Omitting this error state update removes the react error.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const signal = controller.signal;
  fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`, { signal })
    .then(sleeper(1)) // Create some latency
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      setData(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      setData(error); // <-- this is being called after component unmounts!
    });
  return () => {
    controller.abort();
  };
}, [name]);
```

I'd also be willing to bet that the error occurs *every* time but react is just outputting the first and silencing output for subsequent errors.

Comment: Looks right, but doesnt make sense for me... `abort`, as the own name says, should stop a started action and discard all attached actions to it. If `controller.abort()` is actually rejecting it, why not calling it `controller.reject()`? Is there any way to create the logic Im looking for?

Comment: @Rashomon The fetch is aborted and returns a rejected promise, it's *your* code now running and catching the error. I'm sure there is some workaround for this, but nothing immediately comes to mind.